# Invoking Laravel 4 Restful curl in browser URL

Tags: laravel-4, restful-url

I'm finished with this Laravel 4 Restfull tutorial here - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785

What I want to do is to test the Restful link in the browser URL:

curl command:

```
$ curl -i --user firstuser:first_password -d 'url=hxxp://google.com&description=A Search Engine' www.lrvlapp.com/api/v1/url
```

this is running ok, and returning the json as expected:

```
{"error":false,"message":"URL created"}
```

browser URL: I try this:

```
www.lrvlapp.com/api/v1/url?url=hxxp://google.com&description=A Search Engine
```

no error or anything is given and no URL inserted into the database.

this is the UrlController

class UrlController extends \BaseController {

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return 'Hello, API';
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $url = new Url;
    $url->url = Request::get('url');
    $url->description = Request::get('description');
    $url->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    // Validation and Filtering is sorely needed!!
    // Seriously, I'm a bad person for leaving that out.

    $url->save();

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'message' => 'URL created')
    );
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

www.lrvlapp.com is actually my virtual host I setup through the hosts file and apache Virtual Host

The actual location is at: c:\xampp\htdocs\lrvlapp\public

thank you for any answer

Comment: Do you just get a blank screen?

Comment: Yes, got the blank screen

Comment: What is you put a echo 'hello'; die(); in the function - store(). Does that get echoed?

Comment: I do that, but it's getting weirder now, instead of a blank screen I got the 'Hello, API' - seems it invoking the index() function instead

Comment: what if you try www.lrvlapp.com/api/v1/url/store?url=hxxp://google.com&description=A Search Engine

Comment: Im away from keyboard now, will try later, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I somewhat found your article containing this codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are requesting through browser, you are issuing a GET request, which in turn invokes the index method.
You need to submit a POST request to save the url. Then it will invoke the store method. It is the standard way of saving resources.

You can get more clarification in the doc: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

**EDIT**:
If you want to make an ajax call (POST) using jquery in this case, you can call like below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'www.lrvlapp.com/api/v1/url',
            data: { url: "http://google.com", description: "A Search Engine" },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                 <do your actions, for example show some message>          
                 $('#div-id').html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#div-id').html('Error: , ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);

            }
        });
```

Comment: What I want is to call the Restfull method through AJAX for SPA. Any suggestion on the URL to invoke? That is the answer that I want

Comment: The documentation at Laravel website is too minimalistic for a person like me. I learn by example and tutorial.

Comment: hi, could you call the restful method through ajax as I mentioned?

Comment: nope, I think I know what is the problem. Because there is an authentication need to be done when invoking the URL. Directly putting in the URL, will skip the authentication. The tutorial is intended at server side for different apps accessing REST service through authentication

Comment: for url, which is client calling server through AJAX, no need for authentication, as those can be done through web login and session.

Comment: What if the user is a new user, that is your want to store a user registration information in the database, the authentication will deny that. That's my current problem